# Algorithm for creating a map / schematic from a list of travel times?

Tags: graphs

I have data for a warehouse that shows when a person was at a particular bin/shelf (location). As the person moves through the warehouse they build up a profile of how long it takes to get from bin X to bin Y.

I have a lot of this data and it occurred to me that I can use it to construct a schematic of the warehouse bin locations and their distances from each other.

Is there a known / named algorithm for this? I know how to do it by triangulation but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel and there may be issues that others have solved already.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you *do* have, besides the travel time?  Do you have the location of each bin/shelf?  A floorplan for the warehouse?  What would you like to do with the schematic?  Is it for visualization purposes, or is it going to be used by a program, or something else?

Comment: The data is just a pair of nodes and the distance between them. I know roughly the warehouse layout but this is to avoid manually mapping it as there are a lot of bins and they change position. It's mostly to see what comes of it visually, is it possible to recreate a map from this data.

Comment: So you don't know the layout/floorplan of the warehouse?  I suspect it might be hard to reconstruct the layout of the bins, because people don't follow a straight-line path from X to Y (they'll walk along corridors etc.).  If they did, there would be techniques available, but without that... I'm not sure what might be possible.